# Iterate over all rows the set self as foreign key if conditoon is met in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a T-SQL statement to add foreign key to self if a condition is met..

Here's my failed attempt:

```
UPDATE Profile
SET fk_id = CASE 
               WHEN parent_code = code THEN id
               ELSE NULL 
            END
FROM Profile
```

The code executes but the result is not what I expected.

Here's my table:

```
Table Profile as P 
{
    id int
    code varchar
    parent_code varchar
    name varchar
    fk_id int #the foreign key field
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an update join:

```
UPDATE Profile p1
SET p1.fk_id = p2.id
FROM Profile p1
INNER JOIN Profile p2
    ON p1.parent_code = p2.code;
```

The idea here is to try to bring each profile record into alignment with its parent, should it exist, by virtue of its `parent_code` matching some other record's regular `code`.  Should a self join match be made, we then pull the parent `id` into the `fk_id` field of the child record.